# What research has been done into using virtual reality to counteract the psychological effects of extended space travel?

Tags: medical, psychology

One of the biggest challenges in long space flight is the psychological impact it has on the crew.  I've seen a lot of research into preventing the effects, but what about "preventing" the cause without making a huge ship?

Has there been any research into using virtual reality to try and give the astronaut the experience of being in a open environment?

I was only able to turn up [one mention](http://ec.europa.eu/enterprise/policies/space/files/research/fp8_space_hearing/presentations/rittweger-joern_en.pdf) of the idea, but not if it had been studied or if there were any results:

Also, possibly of interest, is [a study that found](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/cpb.2006.9926) that VR could help reduce the symptoms of patients with claustrophobia.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a study, which I believe comes close to the question, is using VR to treat the fear of Flight and claustrophobia. The abstract of the study can be found [here.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12381038)

The goal of the study was to understand the effect of Virtual Reality Graded Exposure Therapy. They had a small sample size of thirty individuals diagnosed with the fear of flying. They were then randomly assigned to one of three groups.

> Three Groups: VRGET with no physiological feedback (VRGETno), VRGET with
>   physiological feedback (VRGETpm), or systematic desensitization with
>   imaginal exposure therapy (IET). Eight sessions were conducted once a
>   week. During each session, physiology was measured to give an
>   objective measurement of improvement over the course of exposure
>   therapy.

Observations during the three month followup revealed significant difference in flying behavior between the groups.

> Only one participant (10%) who received IET, eight of the ten
>   participants (80%) who received VRGETno, and ten out of the ten
>   participants (100%) who received VRGETpm reported an ability to fly
>   without medication or alcohol at three-month followup.

The results suggest that VRGET can be a possible treatment for the fear of flying.
Implications of this procedure could, essentially, be used for treatments of other psychological issues.